# val_loss decreasing on Google Colab whereas increasing on M1 Mac, while using the same parameters and the same dataset

Tags: conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, apple-m1, loss

I'm doing an internship for a Thai University. My mission is to do a land cover of a region using satellite images and machine learning (CNN).
I have to train my model with a dataset of 5 classes.

I'm facing a really weird issue, which is the one that you can read in the title.

My M1 Mac struggles with decreasing the val_loss when running the model.
[val_loss and loss M1 MAC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L1Bn.png)

I tried to run it on Google Colab and it is a lot better.
[val_loss and loss Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9oks.png)

Every model that I run on my M1 Mac showed that problem.

I'm starting to think that my Mac has a problem, does someone know if there is something that I can do to handle that issue?

Here is the network I'm using :

```py
    #parameters layers
    filters_1= 8
    filters_2= 16
    filters_3= 32
    filters_4= 64
    filters_dense = 16
    size = 64
    kernel_size = (3, 3)
    pool_size = 2
    rate = 0.4
    batch_size = 128 
    nb_epoch  = 200
    learning_rate  = 0.0001

        train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale = 1/255,
      rotation_range = 40,
      width_shift_range = 0.2,
      height_shift_range = 0.2,
      shear_range = 0.2,
      zoom_range = 0.2,
      horizontal_flip = True,
      fill_mode = "nearest"
    )

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)  
    
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory= path_train,              #target directory 
        target_size=(size, size),           #resizes all images
        color_mode="rgb",
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="categorical")
    
      
      
    validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory= path_val,
        target_size=(size,size),
        color_mode="rgb",
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="categorical",
        shuffle=False,
        seed=42) #Batch size is done by default by keras
    
    
    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory= path_test,
        target_size=(size, size),
        color_mode="rgb",
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode="categorical",
        shuffle=False)
    
    
    labels = train_generator.class_indices
    label_nb = np.size(list((labels.values())))
    label_nb = train_generator.num_classes # is the same
    label_names = list((labels.keys()))
    num_classes = label_nb

    model = Sequential()                #creation du modèle 
    
    ##LAYER 1##
    layer1 = Conv2D(filters = filters_1, kernel_size= kernel_size, input_shape = (size, size, 3), activation = 'relu')
    model.add(layer1)
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= pool_size ))
    model.add(Dropout(rate))
    model.fit                           #set training to True
    
    ##LAYER 2##
    layer2 = Conv2D(filters = filters_2, kernel_size = kernel_size, activation = 'relu')
    model.add(layer2)
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= pool_size ))
    model.add(Dropout(rate))
    
    ##LAYER 3##
    layer3 = Conv2D(filters = filters_3, kernel_size = kernel_size, activation = 'relu')
    model.add(layer3)
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= pool_size ))
    model.add(Dropout(rate))
    
    ##LAYER 4##
    layer4 = Conv2D(filters = filters_4, kernel_size = kernel_size, activation = 'relu')
    model.add(layer4)
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= pool_size ))
    model.add(Dropout(rate))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    
    ##LAYER 5##
    layer5 = Dense(16,activation = "relu", kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01))
    model.add(layer5)
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(rate))
    
    ##LAYER 6##
    layer6 = Dense(16,activation = "relu", kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01))
    model.add(layer6)
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(rate))
    
    ##LAYER 7##
    layer7=Dense(units = num_classes, activation = 'softmax')     # units: number of nodes in the layer
    model.add(layer7)

    opt  = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    
    model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    speed = 1
    STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size//speed
    STEP_SIZE_VALID=validation_generator.n//validation_generator.batch_size//speed
    STEP_SIZE_TEST=test_generator.n//test_generator.batch_size
    
    #rajouter callback
    callback = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss',
                              min_delta = 0,
                              patience = 50,
                              verbose = 1,
                              restore_best_weights = True)

    h=model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                        steps_per_epoch=100,
                        validation_data=validation_generator,
                        validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                        epochs=nb_epoch, 
                         callbacks = [callback])

Thank you very much :)
```

Comment: same tensorflow version?

Comment: no, on the Mac I have python 3.8 and TF 2.4.0
On Colab I have python 3.7 and TF 2.5.0

Do i have to update TF on the Mac to make it work ?

Comment: yeah. to reduce hypothetical causes. I have happened to see the similar situation and it was a bug in tensorflow.